# Mixing breadcrumbs with a Back button

Tags: lists, user-research, best-practice, categorization

The following is a web app store wireframe. The app listing has used a card layout and the search is on the left top of the listing.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJqgzD.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Is it ok to position the breadcrumb in the top left position and the back button next to it?

Comment: What does the back button do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The back button is unnecessary

The point of the breadcrumbs is reduce the number of actions a user needs to take in order to get to a higher-level page. Therefore, **breadcrumbs provide detailed back button functionality** because users can go back to any previous navigation level. Also, as @Alan pointed out, the back button is already present in the browser, so this is another reason to ditch it in your interface.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of breadcrumbs, hierarchical and historical.

Hierarchical allow users to be oriented and enable quick category scope changes. 
Home>Furniture>Living room furniture>Arm chairs

Historical will return you to where you previously were. In the context of an e-commerce store that will be a 
Furniture>living room furniture>Arm chairs
- (tick box) Leather
- tick box Brown
By using the historical breadcrumb, they can be confident that the filters will still be applied. 
When using the browser back button, sometimes the filtering is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be confusing for the user.

You could add a label to the icon as "back" or "back to previous page" and I'd put the breadcrump farther, above your search bar for example.
Don't forget to link your Home page as the starting point of your breadcrump.
+

Answer (score 0):

Avoid adding back buttons to your website, as every browser has them built in and that's what users expect to use.

There are a few exceptions to this:

- You want to avoid re-sending data in a multi-step action (such as a form)
- Your "site" is a webapp with its own UI and controls

Your mockup looks like a website to me, so I would recommend against the back button.

Comment: I get the idea, but the browser back button doesn't always behave the way the app is structured from its information architecture. Take this example:

If a user fills out a form, sometimes the browser back button can take you back to the the form's blank state before it was filled out instead of taking you to the previous page.